# PySide and QtWebKit: Module could not be found

Tags: python, qt, qtwebkit, qml, pyside

I'm using PySide 1.0.4, Qt 4.7.3 and Python 2.7.2 on Windows XP SP3. Now I simply wanted to run the QML/QtWebKit example from the tutorials. Although I get an strange error during execution in my QML file:

```
import QtWebKit 1.0
WebView { settings.javascriptEnabled: true; width: 400; height: 280 }
```

It says

> file:///main_gui.qml:3:1: plugin cannot be loaded for module "QtWebKit": Cannot load library C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/PySide/imports/QtWebKit/qmlwebkitplugin.dll: The specified module could not be found.

I have already double checked all Path variables. Everything other than the QtWebKit works just fine (PySide, QML). Event if I use the WebKit directly from PySide it works.

Maybe someone got a clue.

Comment: Did you tried `from PySide import QtWebKit`?

Answer (score 2):

when I added: to my .py file and it made it work.  thank you.  had the same prob.

> from PySide import QtWebKit